# GitHub Actions tag filter with branch filter

Tags: github-actions

GitHub actions allow the use of branch and tag filters, but they don't seem to work together.

For example, this workflow runs on pushes to master ***or*** pushes with a tag.

```
name: npm Publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    tags:
      - v*
```

I want to setup a publishing workflow that runs on tagged pushes to master, not just one or the other. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you have any tags that *aren't* on `master`? Because I can't see a way in the docs to do an AND like you're looking for, but if all your `v*` tags are on the master branch then you could try omitting `branches: master` and see if that works. The [docs](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requesttagsbranches) say "Defining only one of `tags:` or `branches:` will mean the workflow skips events affecting the other type of ref."

Comment: It doesn't seem from the docs that this is possible. You might be able to use an `if` conditional in a job step, but it could be a bit of a hack. One option is simply to use `on: release` to trigger the workflow instead of `on: push`. Then it will only trigger when you publish a release, which tags on the master branch.

Comment: @peterevans I hadn't seen that solution. I feel like that is close enough to be worth an answer

Comment: @Kyeotic Added an answer to expand on my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution is to use `on: release` instead of `on: push`. This will trigger the workflow to execute when a release is published via the GitHub UI. When you publish a release on GitHub it tags the `master` branch with the version of the release that you specify. Each execution of the workflow is therefore guaranteed to be a tagged commit on the `master` branch.

```
name: npm Publish

on: release
```

Comment: This is the closest thing I have seen to a solution for this.