# Trigger github workflow only if pushed to specific branch and tag exists

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to trigger a Github workflow only if a code is pushed to a specific branch and if a tag exists, but my config (github workflow) does not work as expected:

```
name: Deployment
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/BRANCH-NAME
    tags:
      - *
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '10.x'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm install

      - name: Lint & build
        run: |
          npm run build
```

The workflow is triggered even if a tag does not exist.

How could I fix this?

Comment: [The example in the documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/configuring-a-workflow#filtering-for-specific-branches-tags-and-paths) says that if you have 'branches' and 'tags' then it triggers for either of them, i.e. they're 'or' not 'and'. No idea if / how you can do 'and' though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rup. It is exactly the 'and' that I want to set up somehow..

Answer (score 23):

**EDIT**: This *workaround* seemed to have solved my problem at the time of writing but I cannot guarantee that it still works as expected.

---

Since I couldn't find a way to implement an `AND` condition (i.e. tagged AND on master), I used the following workaround:

```
name: Worflow demo
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Exit if not on master branch
        if: endsWith(github.ref, 'master') == false
        run: exit -1
      
      - name: Next job ...
```

This will trigger if there is a tagged (e.g. tag `v1.0.0`) commit pushed:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*
```

The first step ('Exit if not on master branch') then checks if the current branch doesn't end with `master` and exits the workflow (the subsequent tests will not start):

```
- name: Exit if not on master branch
  if: endsWith(github.ref, 'master') == false
  run: exit -1
```

Hope this helps someone else as well.

Comment: Are you using this workflow for when you make a release? If so there is a `on: release` event you can use instead of `on: push`. That should achieve what you want because it only triggers when there is a tagged release on the master branch.

Comment: See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963374/github-actions-tag-filter-with-branch-filter/57983436#57983436)

Comment: Currently, I'm not using this workflow for a release. But thanks for your reply!

Comment: @peterevans correct me if I am wrong. `on: release` doesn't trigger when I push multiple tags on default branch

Comment: @Patrick I tried your solution, but github.ref is empty when a tagged commit is pushed

Comment: @rohitsakala Correct. `on: release` only triggers if you create a release via the GitHub API.

Comment: you would actually to go after `github.event.base_ref` to determine if it were on the 'master' or 'main' branch.  `github.ref` will have something like `refs/tags/<theTag>` in it.  Here's an example of a tag push (or release creation) https://github.com/longrunningprocess/gha-sandbox/runs/4861490865?check_suite_focus=true#step:2:212

Comment: @Patrick this doesn't seem to work.  When triggering on tags, `github.ref = refs/tags/<TAG-NAME>` and does *not* include the branch information at all!

Comment: @BillyClark the [`base_ref` documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) says "This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either `pull_request` or `pull_request_target`." Does it actually work on a push tag trigger ?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't seem to work for me, as pointed out by [dilithiummatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230468/dilithiummatrix) in the comments.

So I tried outputting the available values of the github object, which you can do by adding this in your workflow file to see what is available:

```
      - name: Dump job github var
        env:
          GITHUB_VAR: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_VAR"
```

From this I noticed that as [Billy Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10818013/billy-clark) also pointed out, that github.event.base_ref contains refs/heads/production. So this worked for me:

```
      # Only release from prod branch
      - name: Exit if not on production branch
        if: endsWith(github.event.base_ref, 'production') == false
        run: exit -1
```

Answer (score 1):

can use release event and **github.event.release.target_commitish** to make only tags on 'my_branch' to trigger the build

```
name: workflow demo
on:
  release:
    types:
      - published
jobs:
  my_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: build only on my_branch tag
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'release' && github.event.release.target_commitish == 'my_branch'}}
        run: "something"
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the multiple unintended runs I removed the "branches:" scalar and just include and !exclude tags that I want my workflow to run on.

Following runs on tagged releases, not on release candidates:

```
name: 'tagged-release'

  on:
      push:
        tags:
          - 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
          - '!*-rc[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can so by writing the following YAML code.
Keep in mind that you have to put the branches-ignore so that the workflow is not activated when you create branches. The part where you check whether the tag is pushed to a specific branch is covered in the second part of the answer.

```
name: Deployment
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - *
    branches-ignore:
      - '*'
```

You can check for the name of the branch with the following code; specifically for every step of the job you are trying to accomplish.

```
  - name: job
    env:
      BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }} 
    if: contains(env.BRANCH_NAME, <branch-name>)
```

then follow up with some more code you want the workflow to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, for a push tag trigger, `ref_name` is the name of the tag and not the name of the branch on which it has been pushed