# Github Actions Workflow that runs when branch is main AND a matching tag is present

Tags: github-actions

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the events that trigger a workflow respond in an "AND" manner, as they seem to default to "OR" - the below YAML results in the workflow running twice (I presume once in response to the branch being correct and the other being due to the tag being matched):

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    tags:
      - v*
```

What I'm looking for is the workflow to run when the commit is to the main branch and tagged with a `v*` tag. What actually happens is that the workflow will run when *either* of these conditions are true (or twice if they both are).

Is there a way to restrict the workflow to only running when all `on` events are matched?

Comment: I think the short answer is no, you can't restrict the running to a tag that is pushed to a commit on a specific branch:
The answer to this question has a good workaround though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874409/trigger-github-workflow-only-if-pushed-to-specific-branch-and-tag-exists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger github workflow only if pushed to specific branch and tag exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874409/trigger-github-workflow-only-if-pushed-to-specific-branch-and-tag-exists)