# how to trigger github action workflow by creating tags only from main branch?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

Right now if we are creating a tag with any branch, our action workflow starts running. we want to trigger action workflow only if we create a tag from the main branch.
my current YAML file looks like below. let us know what needs to be changed here

```yaml
on:
  push:    
    tags:        
      - '*'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger github workflow only if pushed to specific branch and tag exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874409/trigger-github-workflow-only-if-pushed-to-specific-branch-and-tag-exists)

Comment: @jonrsharpe No its not. because value of github.ref will be name of tag which we have created.

Comment: In the comments it says you want base_ref, they also point to https://stackoverflow.com/q/57963374/3001761